# The attribute send_keys.(ARROW_DOWN) and context_click(clique) does not work

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, sendkeys

AttributeError: 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'send_Keys'

```
clique = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'ReadingContentFooter')]")
actions.context_click(clique)
actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
actions.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
actions.send_Keys(Keys.RETURN)
actions.perform()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you were close. Possibly there was a typo. You need to replace the `K` in caps with `k` in small. Effectively, you need to replace:

```
actions.send_Keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

With:

```
actions.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```